# Jinja2 Loops with Saltstack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I experience a issue with my jinja2 template when using for loops. I guess I'm just to dumb to get the right syntax.

```
{% for options in salt['pillar.get']('nexus.file.nexus.vmoptions') %}
//trying to access a yaml list (posted below)`
{% for addjavavariables in options %}
//trying to get the lists out of the options
  {{ nexus.file.nexus.vmoptions.addjavavariables[0] }}
//trying to write every single line from my list 
  {{ addjavavariables }}:
  - {{ addjavavariables }}
   {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

The YAML looks like this.:

> ```
> nexus:     
>  file:
>   nexus:
>     vmoptions:
>       addjavavariables:
>        - 'Xms1200M'
>        - 'Xmx1200M'
>        - 'XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G'
>        - 'XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions'
>        - 'XX:+UnsyncloadClass'
>        - 'XX:+LogVMOutput'
>        - 'XX:LogFile=../sonatype-work/nexus3/log/jvm.log'
>        - 'Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
>        - 'Dkaraf.home=.'
>        - 'Dkaraf.base=.'
>        - 'Dkaraf.etc=etc/karaf'
>        - 'Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/karaf/java.util.logging.properties'
>        - 'Dkaraf.data=../sonatype-work/nexus3'
>        - 'Djava.io.tmpdir=../sonatype-work/nexus3/tmp'
>        - "Dkaraf.s'tartLocalConsole=false"
>        - 'Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/home/nexus/.java'
> ```

Final file should looks like

```
-Xms1200M
-Xmx1200M
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+UnsyncloadClass
-XX:+LogVMOutput
-XX:LogFile=../sonatype-work/nexus3/log/jvm.log
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dkaraf.home=.
-Dkaraf.base=.
-Dkaraf.etc=etc/karaf
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/karaf/java.util.logging.properties
-Dkaraf.data=../sonatype-work/nexus3
-Djava.io.tmpdir=../sonatype-work/nexus3/tmp
-Dkaraf.s'tartLocalConsole=false
-Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/home/nexus/.java
```

my problem is, that I don't get anything into the file. It also won't go into the loop at all. Can anybody give me a hint, how I can put all the items in the list with a starting dash into the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path separator for [`pillar.get`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/#the-pillar-get-function) is `:`, not `.`, so you should go with `salt['pillar.get']('nexus:file:nexus:vmoptions')`.
But you could also simply use `pillar['nexus']['file']['nexus']['vmoptions']`

A weird thing is that you have 2 `for` loops but only 1 list to iterate over. Is there other keys in the `nexus:file:nexus:vmoptions` dict?

To get the required result, I would go with:

```
{% for addjavavariable in salt['pillar.get']('nexus:file:nexus:vmoptions:addjavavariables', []) %}
-{{ addjavavariable }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked well.

I thought i had to iterate over every item in the list to get the item. I didn't know that i can go for `addjavavariables` and automatically get every item. I thought i always have to go for something like `addjavavariables[index].value`.

I marked your answer as right.

Comment: The `[]` version will raise if anything is missing, while the single key with `:` will not.